# R: error detection

Tags: r

Is there any way to generate a status report in R at the very end of a long code, so that I can tell if anything went wrong with the code without having to spend a minute scrolling up to look for the red error messages? It could something as simple as a Yes or No.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about wrapping your code with a `tryCatch`? You could add handlers  for errors, warnings and messages (possibly print a message to the console), and break the code early if something bad happens.

```
tryCatch(Your_Code,
    error = function(e) {Do something},
    warning = function(w) {Something else},
    message = function(m) {Whatever you want}
  )
```

You can find a great explanation in Hadley Wickham's "[Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Exceptions-Debugging.html)" book.